# How can this wait until the update is finished to move to the next item?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, generator

I want it to wait until .update() is done before going to the next player in the otherPlayers array. I didn't know if generators or something else could work here.

```
let {players} = this.props;

for(let player of otherPlayers) {
  const index = players.findIndex(p => p.Id === player.Id);
  const firebaseId = index && players[index].firebaseId;

  if(index !== -1 && firebaseId !== null) {
    window.firebase.database().ref(`/players/${firebaseId}`)
     .update({...player}, /* Callback possible */);
  } 
}
```

Comment: I think you can found answer in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408718/wait-for-callback-before-continue-for-loop) .

Comment: Do you use ES6 with babel in your code, because you could use the `await` function to make the update waiting to finish.

Comment: I do use ES6 with babel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this possibly.

```
let {players} = this.props;

let p = Promise.resolve(); // just really want a promise to start

for(let player of otherPlayers) {
  const index = players.findIndex(p => p.Id === player.Id);
  const firebaseId = index && players[index].firebaseId;

  if(index !== -1 && firebaseId !== null) {
    p = p.then(()=>{
      return window.firebase.database().ref(`/players/${firebaseId}`)
       .update({...player}, /* Callback possible */);
    });
  } 
}
```

This starts with a resolved promise, which will cause the first update to execute immediately. Each subsequent update is chained on to the resolution of the previous promise.