# then function getting executed before all the asynchronous calls are executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am calling a backend service to fetch all the IDS available in the first fetch from the `loadContent` method and I am getting all the IDS from backend.

With the randomly picked 10 IDS from the initial service,  I am calling another service individualy to fetch the complete data of the ID. I am also able to get all the data, but before getting all the data **the function with dispatch is getting called** due to which the data is not getting set in the store.

```
export function loadContent(requestUrl) {
  return dispatch => {

   return fetch( /* initial calls to get all the ids */ ).then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    }).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      var stories = [];


      var x = 0;
      var loopArray = function(data) {
      return customAlert(data, function() {


        });
      }

      function customAlert(topStories, callback) {
        var randomNumber = topStories[Math.floor(Math.random() * topStories.length)];
        fetch( /* call service with individual id */ ).then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        }).then((output) => {
          console.log(output);
          stories[x] = output;
          x++;

          // any more items in array? continue loop
          if (x <= 10) {
            loopArray(data);
          } else {
            return stories;
          }
        })
      }
     return loopArray(data);
    }).then((stories) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "LOAD",
        payload: stories
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("There has been error");
    })


  };
}

export function load(news) {
  return {
    type: 'LOAD',
    news: news
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` each `Promise` from its inner block so that you can chain them all together and have the `.then((stories)` execute only once they're all complete. Namely, change to:

```
return fetch( /* initial calls to

// ...

return customAlert(data, function() {

// ...

return fetch('to get the...

// ...

if (x <= 10) {
  return loopArray(data);
}
```

so that the initial call of

```
return loopArray(data);
```

will only finally resolve once every other Promise (now properly chained with the initial call) has resolved.

You also might simplify your code by using `push`, for example:

```
stories.push(output);
```

rather than keep an `x` variable of the current length of the `stories` array so you can assign to `stories[x]`.

Also, you may consider using `Promise.all` if you're able to make promises in parallel, so as to reduce the time necessary for the whole function to complete.

Comment: I have added the return but still the same behaviour :(

Comment: @user1645290 You can't physically get same behaviour if you properly chained all promises as the answer prescribes. `callback` in your code looks suspicious. There should be no random callbacks when you use promises, they aren't needed. If async code resides there, it won't work as expected.